# How do you map $\{0,1\}^* \times \{0,1\}^*$ to $\{0,1\}^*$ with a 1-1 function?

Tags: functions

I know how to map $\{0,1\}^*$ to integers but I can not figure this one out.

Comment: What is $\{0,1\}^*$?

Comment: @Nichlos The question's body and title's body are not supposed to be used as one. Please write up the question completly on the question's body.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star
all possible strings using 0 and 1

Comment: Didn't this just come up yesterday? Pretty sure it did.

Comment: Is this your question too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476677/find-1-1-and-onto-mapping-from-0-1-to-the-integers/476720#476720? If yes, you can flag for moderators' attention and merge your two accounts.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is, starting with binary words $u,v$, to interpret $2u2v$ as a ternary number representing $~n\in\Bbb N$, and map it to the binary representation of$~n$ (without leading digit $0$).

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{0, 1\}^*$ is countably infinite and product of countably infinite sets is countably infinite, the claim follows. You can get the function explicitly by composing bijection between $\{0, 1\}^*$ and $\mathbb{N}$ with bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} × \mathbb{N}$. There are standard candidates for those bijections. Ask if you need more explanation.

Comment: but how would I describe such a function?

Comment: @Nichlos: You said you knew how to map $\{0, 1\}^*\to\Bbb N$; is your problem that you don't know how to do that _bijectively_ (which is what this method requires)? Or is your difficulty with an explicit bijection $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ (actually injection would suffice here)?

Comment: For a bijection $\{0, 1\}^*\to\Bbb N$, prefix a digit $1$ to you string, interpret as a binary number, and subtract$~1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bijection 
$$f:\{0,1\}^*\to \mathbb Z.$$
Therefore, you can consider the composition
$$\{0,1\}^*\times\{0,1\}^*\to\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\to \{0,1\}^*,$$
where the first map is the product $f\times f$, the last map is $f^{-1}$, and the middle map is any bijection $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I think $\Bbb Z$ should probably better be $\Bbb N$ througout, but of course it doesn't really matter (as the two are in bijction).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I used $\mathbb Z$ because the OP mentioned he already had the map $f$ (whatever it is), but you're right, it could just as well have been $\mathbb N$

Answer (score 1):

Given $w \in \{ 0, 1\}^*$, define $w_0$ as the string obtained from $w$ by adding a $0$ after each symbol in $w$. Similarly define $w_1$.

Then $(u, v) \mapsto u_0v_1$ is an injection.

Comment: Shorter but less symmetric is $(u,v)\mapsto u_011v$.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same with the proof of the theore "rational numbers are countable". If you're able to map your set to the integers 1-1, then you should be able to prove its Cartesian product with itself can be mapped on itself just like the mapping between rational numbers and natural numbers.

Here is the proof of the countability of the rational numbers:

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countably_Infinite